# How to get single record based on key from firebase realtime databse in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-forms

I am trying to fetch the single record data from firebase database, but I am not able to get single record data from firebase.

I am able to add records to firebase and I am able to get and display in all records in listing.

I am trying to get single record based on `$key`

I uploaded the db json [image]

My dependencies

[image]

My details page components

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-user-details',
 templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
 })
 export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

 id: any;
 userList: any;
 imageUrl: any;

 constructor(private _user: UserService, private router: Router, private 
 arouter: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.id = this.arouter.snapshot.params['id'];
 console.log(this.id);
 this._user.getUserDetails(this.id)
 .subscribe(res => {
  this.userList = res;
 });
 console.log(this.userList);
 }

}
```

My services file :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, FirebaseObjectObservable } 
 from 'angularfire2/database';
import { User } from './user';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

 userList:  AngularFireList<User>;
 folder: any;
 userDetails: AngularFireList<User>;

 constructor(private _fb: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.folder = 'userProfile';
  this.userList = _fb.list('/user');
 }

 getAllUser() {
  return this.userList;
 }

 inserUser(contFrm: User){
  this.userList.push(contFrm);
 }

 getUserDetails(id) {
  this.userDetails = this._fb.list('/user'ref => ref.equalTo(id)).valueChanges());

  return this.userDetails;
  }
```

Its not throwing an any error but i am not able to get record data.

Comment: You didn't return value in `getUserDetails` method

Answer (score 0):

From version 5.0 of AngularFireList, you must chain `valueChanges` after `list` to return Observable
Moreover, you didn't return value in `getUserDetails` method

```js
getUserDetails(id) {
  this.userDetails = this._fb.list('/user', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'fname',
      equalTo: id
    }
  }).valueChanges();

  return this.userDetails;
}
```